# How receiver find out which hashing algorithm to use for data received from sender in digital signature

Tags: encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, cryptographic-hash-function

I understood the process of digital signature

1. sender gives the response as data + hash of data ( hashed with algorithm let’s say X and signed with private key)
2. receiver calculate the hash of data which receiver got from step 1 using algorithm X.
3. If hash, got as response in step 1 from sender(decry pt using public key) and hash receiver calculated from received data are same, we are good but if it is different the data is tampered.

till now everything is fine. but my question is How the receiver or sender decides which algorithm for hashing use. in above case what is the value of X. How to decides that?

As per my understanding receiver should tell as part of request to sender first which hash algorithm it has to use. am i correct?

Please let me know views on it.

Answer (score 1):

The digital signature includes both the digest algorithm and the digest value encoded in ASN.1. See [RFC 3447 PKCS#1 v2.1](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt).

> **A.2.4 RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5**
>
> ```
> DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
>       digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithm,
>       digest OCTET STRING
>   }
> ```

So in the verification process it is possible to determine if the digestAlgorithm used is the expected.

But the usual thing is that the signature algorithm is included as an attribute in the signature format itself, so that the verification part can apply the appropriate one.

**XMLSignature example**
[image: xmldsig]

**JWT/JWS signature**
[image: jwt]

If you are using a format that does not include the signature algorithm, then sender and receiver should agree it previously